# ASP.NET MVC4 How to post and retrieve data unique to a specific user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been learning how to use ASP.NET MVC4 and have been getting my head around authenticating users and user roles and posting data using the entity framework to SQL.

However I have not been able to find any guides/resources (maybe I don't know the correct term) for posting and retrieving data that is unique to an specific user. For example how would a user only see the entries that they created if it was a site that stored data that is personal to each user.

What patterns/designs does one use when trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a sandbox of data for a specific is usually tied to authentication. You can access this many ways through ASP.Net.

First of all, every user gets identified even if they never log in. They get a session identifier. It essentially creates a small place in memory for this user where you can store any user related information. Think of Sessions as walled gardens for each user.

```
 Session["UserFullname"]
```

This works, but realize Session is limited by time, so it is very volatile. Utilize it, but don't depend on it.

The next method is to authenticate a User. This is done using Cookies, but usually handled transparently for you by ASP.Net Membership or other authentication providers. To access the authenticated User you just need to use a simple line in your Controller actions.

```
// User is the property
User.Identity.Name
```

Both these methods can store information about your user that you would use to query data specific to them.

```
 Select * From Orders Where UserId = *User.Identity.Name*
```

Note that both Session and User are accessible through HttpContext.Current as well, as long as you are in a web environment.

```
 HttpContext.Current.User
 HttpContext.Current.Session
```

You won't need to access them this way unless you are not inside your Controller, or inside of another class that doesn't already give you access to the HttpContext. I don't recommend this way either, since your code could be used outside of a web application where HttpContext is not available.

I hope that makes sense, and please feel free to ask me questions.

Comment: Thanks, this will get me going in the direction I was wanting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much about mvc, but more about the problem of relating data to a specific user. You have to ask yourself, how would you identify a piece of data to a user.

The way you would do this is to tie the data to the user in the data store somehow.
In a relational database you would do this by having a User table and using the unique key on that table to insert data into another table such as Order. Order would then have a User Id.

When a user logs in, you could store that ID in session and use that to filter out orders based on the id.